# Post request: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-fetch

I'm making a simple backend API but I keep getting this error when I try to post:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

The first part of the code seems to run but I'm not sure why the rest is erroring. I've tried many solutions and they don't seem to work. I think I'm doing something incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const router = Router(),
      A = require('../../models/A');

router.post('/a/:n/:username', (req, res) => {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ message: 'error' })
    bcrypt.hash(req.params.key, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ message: 'error' })
      if (req.params.n !== hash) return res.json({ message: 'no access' });
    })
  })
  fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${req.params.username}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (!json) return res.json({ message: 'Invalid user.' });
      A.findOne({ id: json.id }).then((id) => {
        if (id) {
          res.json({ id: id.id });
        } else {
          const a = new A({
            id: json.id,
            created: Date.now()
          })
          a.save()
          res.json({ id: json.id })
        }
      })
    });
})

export default router;
```

Comment: Don't you think the code is cascading down whether or not the conditions within your Bcrypt are met or not a cascading effect is surely occurring here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.post('/a/:n/:username', (req, res) => {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ message: 'error' })
    bcrypt.hash(req.params.key, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ message: 'error' })
      if (req.params.n !== hash) return res.json({ message: 'no access' });

      //Do the fetch here
    })
  })
```

The erreor is because execution goes into bcrypt.has callback AND fetch. So the same request has more than one `res.json`,

Comment: I also recommand you to add a `.catch` to the fetch for error case, to use `return a.save().then( () => res.json({id:json.id});` to have everything correctly using asynchronous